# call sub within a function doesn't work properly

Tags: excel, vba

My primary goal is to use GoalSeek within a VBA function, which allows me to pass different functions as variables into it.
I tried to write a sub which can perform properly if its been called directly (By just pressing F5). However, when I add this sub into a function and run that function, this sub seems to work but gets me no result. (It can give me a msgbox so I believe it's been called but just didnt perform goalseek).

```
Sub mygoalseek2()

Range("O3").GoalSeek goal:=0, changingcell:=Range("O1")

End Sub
```

```
Function testfun(tgtcell As Range, chgcell As Range, tgtvalue As Double) As Boolean

Call mygoalseek2
testfun = True

End Function
```

This is what I expect to get, when the sub is run directly

[image: text desc]

This is when I change cell O1 into any arbitrary number and run the function "testfun" and get the number unchanged

[image: text desc]

I tried running that sub directly which gave me correct result. I called it within a function expecting the same result but it didnt work, without giving any error message.

Comment: Updating other cells from functions situated in a cell itself doesn't work.

Comment: See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value.